# Is the builtin property class thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
Check the code below:

class A(object):
    @property
    def db(self):
        if not getattr(self, '_db', None):
            self.__create_db()
        return self._db

    def __create_db(self):
        self._db = 'created db a heavy operation'


a = A()
print(a.db)
print(a.db)
```

Is call to method db in class A thread-safe? I mean, is it ensured that two threads won't end up calling __create_db?

Comment: I wouldn't think so ... If I were you, I'd guard it with a lock ...

Comment: It's possible both threads enter the if, so no

Comment: @mgilson . Yes. That is a safest option. But I am using a library which has too many such methods and doing it neatly may be some work. Also, I don't want to use same lock for each property, but using a separate lock for each property also doesn't look good.